# Rails: _destroy attribute in a nested model skips validates_presence_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm following the [Nested Model Form Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).

But I have one problem.

If I add `validates_presence_of :answers`:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :survey
 validates_presence_of :answers
 has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, 
        :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? },  
        :allow_destroy => true
end
```

The `_destroy` skips the Question model validation. So I can update the Question model with empty answers.

I'm probably doing it wrong. How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also asked this question and found the answer.

This link describes the problem better (from my question) and has the answer to it too.
http://homeonrails.com/2012/10/validating-nested-associations-in-rails/

Basically he rejected those that are marked for destruction and counted the remaining ones.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you do not want to `:validates_presence_of :answers`, I think you want `:validates_associated :answers` which will run Answer's validations.

Comment: Actually, I used: validates_associated :answers and validates_length_of :answers, :minimum => 1. validates_presence_of I used only for easier illustrate. validates_associated only validates if the association is valid, don't validates if the association exists